# Parallels - Route trafic thru virtual machine

Tags: networking, macos, virtual-machine, routing, parallels

Scenario:

I have a Macosx with a Windows 10 virtual machine running inside with Parallels.
This image of Windows is corporative and has a vpn client to connect to internet. 
I want to send all the traffic thru this vpn connection (that I can't install in Maxosx).

Is there any method to route all the traffic thru vpn connection in Parallels virtual machine?